# Jenkins fighting with Django over permissions

Tags: nginx, django, jenkins, sqlite

I've got a Jenkins/Nginx server running. But I get the error from Django:

```
 attempt to write a readonly database
```

So I solved this problem by changing the ownership of the project folder to the default user:

```
chown -R joren .
```

Now Django is working properly, but Jenkins doesn't seem to agree because now it is unable to build due to permission errors.

How do I get both sides to work together properly?

**Edit:**

Nginx is runnings as *www-data*

Jenkins is running as *jenkins*

**Edit2:**

The job builds the directory from a git repository, activates the virtualenv, tests the django apps (and other django-specific operations) and then restarts the server. The `src` subdirectory of the directory to which it is built, is the root of the nginx server.

**The workaround:**

Switch sqlite3 for postgresql3. Still looking for a proper solution though.

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: @ChristopherPerrin sqlite, like the tag says.

Comment: I didn't see the tag. Do Jenkins and Django need to use the same database?

Comment: @ChristopherPerrin Jenkins gets the database from the repository and writes it to the django directory.

Comment: You need to consider this: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

Comment: @Herson I don't think that is the issue, since jenkins writes the database only once every build and leaves it alone after that. Django uses it after that, so only one user at a time writes.

Comment: can you describe what the job is doing in more details? A standard job should fetch and do things with the application entirely with jenkins user, if you are keeping your application elsewhere managed by you and not by jenkins, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Make a group for jekins and django, then give the group write permissions.

Comment: As kneejerk reactions go for dealing with permission issues, this'll work beautifully when the issue is reading or executing simultaneously. But if two processes are both trying to write to the same file, the permissions are actually preventing corruption and race conditions. I didn't downvote you, but I don't think your solution would solve the OP's issue.